# How to store a variable value obtained in home page across all pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, dom

I am using jquery to fetch inner html value of a div in home page, and I want this value to be accessible in all pages. The problem i'm facing is that the div from which i'm getting the value is present only in home page, so when the script runs in other page, the value will be undefined as the div is not present.

The issue is, they are displaying a message in bottom of home page and we want it to be displayed in top part of all pages. so I used jquery to extract the text content and display it in top part, but when we go to other pages, the script fails as the bottom of that page wont have the message.

Comment: So why no make it available on all the pages you need it? You can't get it from a page that is not being loaded with jQuery.

Comment: You can use the browser's local storage, see [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: What will you do if someone doesn't arrive on the homepage, and instead visits a page directly? The solution to this kind of thing is usually not to figure out how to store the value, but instead how to get the value printed on every page.

Comment: so, the webpage is only for internal user, with no access to outsiders. default login page is home page. The software is provided by 3rd party vendor and we dont have access to full code base.  Added more details to question now.

Answer (score 0):

store it in a local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('myItem', myValue);
```

and then you could Access this item on all pages

```
var item = localStorage.getItem('myItem');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

You can use web storage objects like: **sessionStorage** or **localStorage**, 
but be careful with the data you store, which determines which method to use.

- Data in **sessionStorage** is cleared when the page session ends.
- Data stored in **localStorage** has no expiration time.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Window localStorage Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) as solution to your problem. Another option is `sessionStorage`. It depends what you trying to achieve. Look at the definition for both of them and use appropriate.